# control flow from socket to netdevice linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, socket.io

I am trying to implement new netdevice driver in linux. I developed the new netdevice , but i don't know how to link the developed netdriver to socket or how to call my netdevice from
socket.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

i think this link will help u..

http://www.linuxfoundation.org/collaborate/workgroups/networking/kernelflow

just follow the path given in the image..

http://www.linuxfoundation.org/images/1/1c/Network_data_flow_through_kernel.png